# How to test/search for values in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to check whether a specific value in a dictionary is present. It seems that with keys, a simple `if 'x' in 'dictionary'` statement works, yet not for values.

```
dictionary = {
    'First': '1',
    'Second': '2',
    'Third': '3'
}

if 'First' in dictionary:
    print('First is here')

if '1' in dictionary:
    print('1 is here')
```

So the obvious logical error is that the output only reads:

```
First is here
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the dictionary's values, you need to call [`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

```
if '1' in dictionary.values():
```

It is not necessary to call [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) however:

```
if 'First' in dictionary.keys():
```

because the `in` operator iterates over the dictionary, which yields its keys.

Comment: Though for keys you should be able to just do `if 'First' in diction`. Oh, sorry, I see that was what the OP did. NM

Comment: Yeah, got it now. Sorry :-)  (Need more coffee)

Answer (score 2):

Read the [docs on `dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The `key in d` operator on a dictionary looks for a key in the `dict`'s keys, not its values.

To look in the values, use `value in d.values()`.

Also, this is a less efficient O(size of dict) operation. If you're constantly searching for values, you should generally use a different data structure (maybe a sorted list depending on the exact use case).